# Fixed container relative to a DIV - is this possible?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I'm looking for a way to make navigation arrows (red boxes) follow the screen this way:

[image]

But I can not find a way to put them there... it would be very easy to put them to the very left and very right but I'd like it to be in the middle and it's a bit problematic. I managed to make it work in 90% of browsers (green solution) but it's not perfect and it doesn't work in some popular browsers.

UPDATE #1: There's one more important thing - I'd like red boxes to be sometimes above 600px content (on small resolutions around 600px and below).

UPDATE #2: 600px container has actually: `max-width: 1600px; width: 90%;` and `600px` is just an example resolution to better illustrate the gap.

Comment: Consider not using a parent container for the red boxes. Also you may put them inside the 600px wide element (needs `position: relative;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this](http://codepen.io/ByScripts/pen/psihx) ?

You can play with the max-width to test with multiple widths.

Check if that suit you.

---

I copy the code here, for "future-proofness" (if one day codepen disappear)

#### HTML

```
<div id="buttons">
  <div id="left">L</div>
  <div id="right">R</div>
</div>

<div id="foobar">
  <div id="content">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#foobar {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

#content {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#buttons {
  width: 700px;
  margin-left: -350px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;

}
#left, #right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute; 
  background-color: red;
}
#right {
  right: 0
}
```

#### JS (JQUERY)

```
$(function(){
  refresh_buttons = function(){
    w = $('#foobar').width() + 100;
    $('#buttons')
      .css('width', w)
      .css('margin-left', -w/2);
  };

  refresh_buttons();
  $(window).resize(refresh_buttons);
})
```

Comment: Thanks! It's almost there! But when I add more content, buttons go down and they are no longer in the middle of the current screen, they are below the content.

Comment: I managed to make arrows appear in the middle of the content but still they don't follow the screen. I think that usage of `position: fixed;` somewhere is unavoidable.

Comment: Yes, that's what I managed to do as well but if you add even more content you'll notice that arrows are in the middle of it and they don't follow the screen. I came to conclusion that in this particular situation it's better to use @media queries and perhaps 2 sets of containers. Or even more controls for mobile phone to the very bottom :) It would save a lot of hassle. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Removed the "height: 300px;" I put it for demo only, but it should be here. Edit: I think I didn't understood... you want the arrow in the middle of the screen only ? Whatever the content is ?

Comment: Maybe with a little bit of jQuery : http://codepen.io/ByScripts/pen/psihx ? (try to resize the window to see it in effect)

Comment: Edited the answer with the new proposition

Comment: Thanks! It works very well now! I think I'll go with CSS only solution though and 2 containers because I try to avoid JS where possible. Thank you for that code :) I'm sure that it's going to be useful to anybody that is looking for the same kind of behavior!

Answer (score 1):

yes you can. use left or right at 50% and then adjust margin left or right depending on which you used.
assuming your box has 100px width:

```
#box1{
    position: fixed;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right:-300px; //adjust more or less as you want
}
#box2{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-300px; //adjust more or less as you want
}
```

Comment: this will work if your boxes are inside or outside your centered container

Comment: What if the container in the middle is responsive (like: `max-width: 1000px; width: 92%;`)? Actually it is responsive and I gave 600px only as an example :)

Comment: he specified that the container is 600px

Comment: i said this by heart, let me give a try

Comment: if you give it a percentage value, such as 82% you divide the difference to 100 by two, gives you 9%. So,
#box1 {left: 9%; margin-left: -100px;}
#box2 {right: 9%; margin-right: -100px;}

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but it behaves differently on different resolutions. Sometimes it's alright and sometimes it's too far from the content or it overlaps it.

Comment: yes, because the boxes have a fixed width on pixels, if you use the boxes size as percentage it will work better

Comment: I would prefer to use the first example with about -400px margins on a 600px width.